# Нужно выбрать легчайший линукс по удобству использования

Tags: linux, gui, ос, x86-64

Нужно выбрать Линукс, ну уж для очеееень слабого ноутбука, естественно x64. Линукс, являющийся эталоном легкости/удобства использования. Ноутбук будет использоваться в учебных(Zoom, office) целях, так же планируется изучать программирование (Python, CSS, HTML5, Javascript, Go). Хотелось бы иметь поддержку всех необходимых пакетов приложений. Подводя итог, нужна рабочая машинка для учебы и кодинга в каком-нибудь соблайме))

Поискав в интернете, нашел один из легчайщих Линуксов с GUI, Puppy Linux, но не уверен в его работоспособности, трудно ли будет устанавливать софт, да и запускать его вообще?

P.s. Добавил:
Что бы вы понимали под, что я имею в виду под слабым - необходим линукс который в стоке потребляет не больше 500 мб памяти))

Comment: Все эзотерические дистрибутивы (Puppy Linux, DSL, и т. д.) не очень-то практичны. Возьмите Arch Linux и какой-нибудь легкий windows manager типа DWM или OpenBox. И будет у вас < 500 MiB в стоке.

Comment: благодарю за внимание)

Comment: Мне кажется даже самый популярный Ubuntu подойдёт, просто поставить на него минимальное число программ при первой установке, или удалить лишние потом. Также важно чтобы при старте системы минимальное число программ висело в ОЗУ, т.е. отредактировать список стартующих при запуске программ и сделать минимальным. Ubuntu хорош тем что это самый популярный линукс, с ним будет удобней всего и меньше проблем. Редкие другие дистрибутивы просто будут часто не удобные или не совместимы для каких то программ или железа. Просто надо Ubuntu установить/настроить под легковесность.

Comment: благодарю за внимание)

Comment: какие Ubuntu? какие ArchLinux? для RAM < 500Mb? Вы че курите? У вас выбор только из этих ArchBang, Tiny Core Linux, Elive, Porteus, Puppy Linux, SliTaz, WattOS, Bodhi Linux. Из них Puppy Linux на мой взгляд самый дружелюбный. И никаких там Firefox ставить бесполезно. Максимум Midori, на худой конец Palemoon

Comment: большое спасибо за ответ)

Comment: На самом деле, основную часть памяти жрёт GUI в любом дистрибутиве Linux. А ядра у них у всех практически одинаковые. Так что, мой совет: Ставьте **любой** дистрибутив, но в качестве оконного менеджера выбирайте не KDE и даже не Gnome, а что-то совсем простое. Типа  : "LXQt/LXDE vs. Xfce

LXQt и LXDE легче, чем Xfce, но это только часть истории. Прямо скажем так, LXDE выглядит просто. С достаточными усилиями Xfce - более современная среда. Основное различие между LXQt и Xfce заключается в том, что LXQt использует Qt, а не GTK+. Если вы предпочитаете GTK+, лучше использовать Xfce."

Comment: Если же этого окажется недостаточным, то тогда придётся ужимать ядро. Дело это не простое, но зато - очень эффективное. Если из ядра **выкинуть** всё, что не нужно для работы Вашего ноута, то размер ядра сократится в разы, а то и в десятки раз. Относительно простой путь - Gentu (https://www.gentoo.org/)/ Более сложный: LFS (https://habr.com/ru/post/257663/)

Comment: большое спасибо)

Comment: @DiD, вы сами пробовали ими пользоваться? Максимум, что можно сделать с этими дистрибутивами — поиграться вечерок другой. Лично у меня Arch Linux занимает 440 MiB памяти с запущенными иксами, DWM, терминалом (Allacrity) и композитным менеджером (тени окошек).

Comment: @Sergey, ну ужать ядро можно и с помощью `make localmodconfig`. Размер ядра это уменьшит, правда размер потребляемой памяти — нет, ядро все-равно выгружает модули, которые не использует.

Comment: @DiD Я уверен Ubuntu отлично может в 500МБ ОЗУ влезть, это очень много памяти. Ядро само совсем небольшую часть ОЗУ от всего запущенного занимает, явно что малую часть от 500МБ займёт. Главное то чтобы убрать из авто-загрузки при старте всё лишнее, особенно большое в настройках. Даже не мешает количество установленных программ, если диска много, все установленные роли не играют пока не запустили их в ОЗУ. Ну и важно, чтобы запущенные программы компактные брались. А это главное GUI, который больше всего занимает, просто выбрать компактный менеджер и Ubuntu 100% подойдёт тогда.

Comment: @Arty, ЕМНИП, в Ubuntu в качестве DM используется Unity — вещь довольно прожорливая и занимает она (опять же ЕМНИП) явно больше 500 MiB памяти. Даже в **минимальных** системных требованиях Ubuntu Desktop Edition: «4 GiB RAM (system memory)».

Comment: @eanmos Я имел ввиду, чтобы взять Ubuntu за стартовую основу, т.к. это самый популярный и поддерживаемый всеми дистрибутив. А дальше установив его, просто донастроить всё что нужно. А именно тяжёлый GUI заменить на легковесный, в убунту тоже можно GUI менеджер заменять несложно, установить легковесный и заменить старт стандартного на старт легковесного. Также дополнительно ещё из авто запуска при старте убрать все другие тяжёлые программы. И всё готово. Любой линукс включая убунту можно полностью перенастроить, т.е. стартовать со стандартной поставки и доработать настройки.

Comment: @Arty, зачем устанавливать Ubuntu, чтобы потом сидеть и все из нее удалять? Почему бы сразу не установить популярный и легковесный дистрибутив?

Comment: @Arty, вот и я про то же. Можно изначально поставить линукс какой-нибудь ddwrt, и постепенно просвещаясь, думать как к нему приладить программы одну-за-одной. А можно изначально поставить такую ОС, что 99% времени будет уходить на поиск путей оптимизации и ожидания загрузки всего и вся.

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле, основную часть памяти жрёт GUI в любом дистрибутиве Linux. А ядра у них у всех практически одинаковые. Так что, мой совет: Ставьте любой дистрибутив, но в качестве оконного менеджера выбирайте не KDE и даже не Gnome, а что-то совсем простое. Типа : "LXQt/LXDE vs. Xfce LXQt и LXDE легче, чем Xfce, но это только часть истории. Прямо скажем так, LXDE выглядит просто. С достаточными усилиями Xfce - более современная среда. Основное различие между LXQt и Xfce заключается в том, что LXQt использует Qt, а не GTK+. Если вы предпочитаете GTK+, лучше использовать Xfce."
– Sergey 8 минут назад

Если же этого окажется недостаточным, то тогда придётся ужимать ядро. Дело это не простое, но зато - очень эффективное. Если из ядра выкинуть всё, что не нужно для работы Вашего ноута, то размер ядра сократится в разы, а то и в десятки раз. Относительно простой путь - Gentu (gentoo.org/) Более сложный: LFS (habr.com/ru/post/257663)
– Sergey 2 минуты назад

Спасибо Sergey за ответ)